# How would you test for parallel trends in a panel data set of 2 time periods under DDD framework?

Tags: difference-in-difference, trend, parallel-analysis

Suppose i have a panel data with 2 time periods (pre and post events), how would i test for parallel trends assumption under a DDD framework?

Comment: Difference in difference in differences?

Comment: Yes. Triple Difference estimation